# Stored procedure date validation not check with existing dates for a particular ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This stored procedure is used to check the date validation that any user can't apply a 
leave for same time period which 
is applied previous in same time period.
this is working properly .
but if any user want to update leave duration then it can't work

> like if user previous aaplied for leave - 12 may 2013 to 19 may 2013
>   and the registerLeaveID(which is unique field in leave table) is 14.
>
> if user want to update leave duration 14 may 2013 to 16 may213 for
>   same registerLeaveID then this stored procedure compare the new leave
>   date with this registerLeaveID(12) date also.

how can stop to not check the date validation with the registerleaveID dates

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
@startdate datetime,@enddate datetime,@Userid int ,@Registerid

AS
BEGIN
SELECT  Count(*)  FROM leave 
WHERE 
(

(UserID=@userid)

 AND 

 (
      (@startdate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
      OR 
      (@enddate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate) 
      OR
        (
            (@startdate <= Startdate AND @enddate>=EndDate)
        )
  )

)

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
@startdate DATETIME, @enddate DATETIME, @Userid INT, @Registerid INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(*)
    FROM   leave
    WHERE  ((UserID = @userid)
            AND ((@startdate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
                 AND (@Registerid <> Registerid)
                 OR (@enddate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
                 OR ((@startdate <= Startdate
                      AND @enddate >= EndDate))));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_AddTestData_UsingExists
(
    @Name varchar(50),
    @Qualification varchar(50)
) 
AS
DECLARE @Result int
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM
        TestData WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE
        [Name] = @Name AND
        Qualification = @Qualification
)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = -1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TestData
        (
            [Name],
            Qualification
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @Name,
            @Qualification
        )
        SELECT @Result = @@ERROR
    END
IF @Result <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
    END
```